# What does the red text in SystemVerilog LRM 3.1a signify?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm looking for an accepted definition of what the red colored text in the [SystemVerilog LRM 3.1a](http://www.eda.org/sv/SystemVerilog_3.1a.pdf) signifies.  I can intuit what the red text means for the most part.  However, when I went looking for a formal declaration of what the formatting signified, I couldn't find one.  That brings up the second part of this question.  What Accelera document specifies the different formats and semantics used in the LRM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3.1a LRM for SystemVerilog is very out dated, use [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html).

From Annex A (Formal Syntax) in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html):

> The formal syntax of SystemVerilog is described using Backus-Naur Form (BNF). The syntax of SystemVerilog source is derived from the starting symbol source_text. The syntax of a library map file is derived from the starting symbol library_text. The conventions used are as follows:
>   — Keywords and punctuation are in **bold-red** text.
>   — Syntactic categories are named in nonbold text.
>   — A vertical bar ( | ) separates alternatives.
>   — Square brackets ( [ ] ) enclose optional items.
>   — Braces ( { } ) enclose items that can be repeated zero or more times.

3.1a LRM used the same syntax formatting. The syntax description (also Annex A (Formal Syntax) for 3.1a) says "Keywords and punctuation are in **bold** text" with the word bold in red color, so 3.1a meant **bold-red** not bold.